# Wordpress sibling page navigation breaks footer on pages that don't have siblings

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, children, siblings

I'm trying to edit my theme (child theme of twentytwentyone) to add page navigation between siblings, but I don't want show the navigation on pages that do not have siblings.

I've found a bit of code that is working for me for the most part, but something about it makes the page stop short and not show footers on pages that don't have siblings.

In my child theme's **functions.php** I have this code

```
<?php // function to find location within array
function relative_value_array($array, $current_val = '', $offset = 1) {
$values = array_values($array);
$current_val_index = array_search($current_val, $values);

if( isset($values[$current_val_index + $offset]) ) {
return $values[$current_val_index + $offset];
}
return false;
};

// previous page link function
function dbdb_prev_page_link() {
global $post;

if ( isset($post->post_parent) && $post->post_parent > 0 ) {
$children = get_pages('&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=asc&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);
};

// throw the children ids into an array
foreach( $children as $child ) { $child_id_array[] = $child->ID; }

$prev_page_id = relative_value_array($child_id_array, $post->ID, -1);

$output = '';
if( '' != $prev_page_id ) {
$output .= '<a href="' . get_page_link($prev_page_id) . '"> &laquo; '. get_the_title($prev_page_id) . '</a>';
}
return $output;
};

//next page link function
function dbdb_next_page_link() {
global $post;

if ( isset($post->post_parent) && $post->post_parent > 0 ) {
$children = get_pages('&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=asc&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&parent='.$post->post_parent);
};
// throw the children ids into an array
foreach( $children as $child ) { $child_id_array[] = $child->ID; }

$next_page_id = relative_value_array($child_id_array, $post->ID, 1);

$output = '';
if( '' != $next_page_id ) {
$output .= '<a href="' . get_page_link($next_page_id) . '">'. get_the_title($next_page_id) . ' &raquo;</a>';
}
return $output;}
```

and I've added the actual navigation links to my theme's **content-page.php**

```
<div class="prevnext alignwide">
  <div class="alignleft"><?php echo dbdb_prev_page_link(); ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php echo dbdb_next_page_link(); ?>/div>
</div>
```

I believe that something in the functions (perhaps an if statement?) is causing the loop to break before it displays the footer on the bottom of my pages, and it also breaks the Nav menu at the top making it not show subpages/children but I can't figure it out. I would really appreciate any help with this. The page I'm working on is https://voicefromthevoid.com/staging/

Comment: its borking on dbdb_prev_page_link not dbdb_next_page_link, enable error reporting WP_DEBUG etc, check error log

Comment: Thanks Laurence. I cleaned up some of the php tags in the code and enabled debugging. It seems that there's null variables. 

 [12-Jan-2022 22:41:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $children in /home/succul12/voicefromthevoid.com/staging/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/functions.php on line 36
[12-Jan-2022 22:41:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in... 

I need to figure out how to make it do a check and only run on pages with children. any ideas how best to implement?

Comment: you define `$children` only if it enters the if statement, which its not for prev, so its null/undefined, define `$children = [];` above the if statement

Comment: you should do it also for $child_id_array, as if $children is empty that also wont get set

Comment: Upon making those changes, the code "works" and the page doesn't break--the page fully loads, and footer and top navigation menu work properly, with no debug.log generated. But, now the next page link isn't working, only previous.

Comment: do the same for dbdb_next_page_link too

Comment: Unfortunately I already have. I'm wondering if it's resetting the array or something when it gets defined again. sorry I'm just good enough with google and coding to be dangerous. It seems like it works, but just isn't adding anything to the array, so offers no links.  You can see the effect on the page https://voicefromthevoid.com/staging/prose/non-fiction/ it will let you go to previous page, Fiction, and then previous page, Flash, but the forward link doesn't appear.

Comment: it seems I accidentally had the `$chid_id_array = []; ` after the foreach statement. I believe it is fixed now and thank you. Now I just need to figure out a way to exclude it from running on specified pages, or add it to certain pages with shortcode.